# JetBrains Rider - configure appsettings overrides

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings, rider

I am trying JetBrains Rider for my existing .NET Core project. In the project I have several `appsettings.json` overrides:

- `appsettings.Development.json` - for development
- `appsettings.Test.json` - for testing
- `appsettings.Staging.json` - for staging environment
- etc.

In Visual Studio, the overrides work perfectly and I always get my Development override, when running the app in debug mode. However, in Rider I am getting the default `appsettings.json` values, which are not suitable for debugging and development. How do I change the settings to get the values from the correct override?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll need to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable.

To do this, create separate configurations for each environment:[image]

Then click Edit Configurations

I create one for each env - and specify the Environment variable as appropriate:[image]

Comment: Note that this setting in the configuration overrides the actual environment variable; I had exported it in my ~/.bash_profile but it was always reverting to Production.

Comment: No matter what Environment Variables I set in the Run Config, it always selects appsettings.json

Comment: @Tom -- did you ever get this working?  Does not work for me, I always get the main `appsettings.json` copied to output.

Comment: @realmikep Yes, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951660/5950725. If you're working on a shared project, it may cause colleagues issues if you check in the setting, though.

Answer (score 10):

**For the Mac interface:**

1. Choose the config you wish the to change the environment

   [image]
2. Select Environment variables
3. Choose 'Development' or 'Production'

   [image]

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to enter the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` in to the "*Runtime arguments*" field:

[image]

[image]

[image]